# HP Proliant DL120 G7 with P212/256MB SmartArray Controller GPT Support

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array, gpt

I have the `HP Proliant DL120 G7` server with `P212/256MB` SmartArray Controller configured with `4 - 2TB` drives as `RAID 1+0` (4TB usable space).

I would like to have a small partition for my Linux OS and the rest as a single large partition for home.

Is this possible as the home partition would be larger than `2TB`?

Any help would be greatly appreciated as the HP Tech Support has been useless; they recommended Raid 5!

Comment: Yes, it's possible to have a partition larger than 2TB... Is there another Question in there I'm not seeing?

Comment: This question really helped me with another problem I had with the DL120 G7 server. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HP Smart Array controllers previously did not allow logical disk sizes greater than 2.2TB. [This has changed recently](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&taskId=115&prodSeriesId=1157687&prodTypeId=329290&objectID=c01146234&aoid=35252), but in the case of your ProLiant DL120 G7, there may be an incompatibility as detailed in this [customer document](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&taskId=115&prodSeriesId=1157687&prodTypeId=329290&objectID=c01146234&aoid=35252).

The [Quickspecs for the P212 controller](http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/13203_na/13203_na.html) show that >2TB LUNS are available now. Make sure you've updated to the most recent [firmware for the controller](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareDescription.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodTypeId=329290&prodSeriesId=3885791&prodNameId=3885792&swEnvOID=4103&swLang=8&mode=2&taskId=135&swItem=MTX-2a4fd2395826468dad49bb19e3) and for your [DL120 G7 server](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/DriverDownload.jsp?prodNameId=5075937&lang=en&cc=us&prodTypeId=15351&prodSeriesId=5075933&taskId=135). Try from there and see if it works.

Comment: All of the PCIe Pxxx-series HP controllers support >2TB disks by the way, the last one the didn't on day one (though was fixed with an update in '08) was the PCI-X P600.

Comment: I was referring to the logical drive size limits.

Comment: I really thought that went away a few years ago - either way he's laughing with a P212 so long as the OS supports it.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a problem at all, so long as your kernel has GPT (actually "EFI GUID Partition support") support. Glad you avoided R5 :)